# check if password contains username jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is the code i have and its doing something, just not what i need it to. Any help?

```
reee = /$('#username').val()/;
  if(reee.test($('#password').val()))
```

i even tried it as

```
    reee = $('#username').val();
      if(reee.test($('#password').val()))
```

my function stops at this if statement if i dont include the / (im kind of new to jquery so im not 100% sure that the / do but i know if i gave a range like `/0-9/` it will see if a number is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reee = new RegExp($('#username').val(),g);
  if(reee.test($('#password').val()))
```

try that...

or `check if password contains username`

why not use `indexOf`?

```
var username = "reigel";
var password = "reigelgallarde"
alert(password.indexOf(username) != -1); // alerts true
```

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stristr (haystack, needle, bool) {
    // Credit to Kevin van Zonneveld
    var pos = 0;

    haystack += '';
    pos = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf((needle + '').toLowerCase());
    if (pos == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (bool) {
            return haystack.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
            return haystack.slice(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
stristr($('#password').val(), $('#username').val());
```

Comment: is this from another post? can i get a link?