# Php email/password verfication similar string

Tags: php, security, scripting

I want to test before registration email and password, the goal is to refuse the password if it contains any portion of the username or email.

And secondly, it cannot include common dictionary words.

Any idea or link to help me ?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894750/check-if-password-contains-username-jquery

Comment: Yes, it's almost that. My big problem is to compare email with password because user can add special chars "."  "-" or "_". And the dictionary test need a external library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this code a try. I believe this will help

```
<?php
$username = "Zameer";
$email = "zameer.khan@email.com";
$password = "thisiszameer";

if (stripos($password, $username) !== false) {
    echo "Password contains username";
}
else if (stripos($password, $email) !== false) {
    echo "Password contains email";
}
else {
    echo "Does not contain username or email";
}
```